# Finding the CSS selector that is adding a border or padding to a menu item

Tags: css, border, less, joomla3.0

I am working on a Joomla 3.0.3 site using the Gantry 4.1.7 Framework and am having a problem with CSS that is adding a border or some padding/margin on a 1st level menu item.

As you can see from the image below, there is an offset of 1px on the left of the top-level menu item "Références".

[image]

I have tried to find the selector that is causing that and I have not been able to identify it.

The site is online behind password protection. I have created a username and password pair to let someone here access the site for assistance. I would post the code, but as there are so many different files and I have no what is causing this, I hope someone can give me some advice.

The site is accessible at: [Betelec Dev Site](http://dev.betelec.ch)

**username**: stackoverflow
**password**: assists

I would be happy to provide someone (via email or private chat) with either super admin access or ftp access (unfortunately, no ssh on the client's dev machine).

Comment: "I would be happy to provide someone with either super admin access or ftp access" I'm... not sure that's a good idea, ever.

Comment: well, it would be temporary, and I would have a local copy of everything and can reset...but generally speaking, you are correct.

Comment: He's correct with a full stop. Give someone a super admin access and they'll then decide how temporary that access is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
menu li:hover > .dropdown, .gf-menu li.active:hover > .dropdown { 
left: -1px;
opacity: 1;
top: auto;
}
```

Maybe this: left:-1px; ???

Comment: nope...commenting that line out or changing it from -1px to 0 doesn't affect the top level menu. All that happens is that the drop-down no longer displays.

Comment: Well, if I change this to left:0px; dropdown menu is displayed corectly and there is no position offset between dorp down menu and menu bar. I use Opera 12.14.

Comment: well, didn't work for me the first time, but I tried it again, and it worked. Thank you.